# Control movement issue

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

I am updating a **VB.NET 1.1** application to **VB.NET 4.0** and currently having an issue with label and text control movement when displayed on the winform. During run time, the text box and labels move as shown by the image below. After numerous research I have no idea what is causing this problem. Have any one experience this before? Where various controls move position during run time from where they are supposed to be, perhaps as a result of different display resolutions?

[image: Label and Textbox strange display]

Comment: I don't see anything moving in your picture. Do you mean the controls appear in one place when you look at them in the designer and somewhere else at run time? Have they all moved the same distance in the same direction?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. *Has anyone ever seen this?* is not a very good question

Comment: Yes, the text box and label within the grid above belongs below with the other label called: Manual Total. Within Visual Studios, they are in the correct spot. But during run time they move up randomly.

Comment: You can record a shot clip for the movement part?

Answer (score 1):

DPI scaling changed between .Net 1.1 and .Net 2.0. Take a look at this article for more info:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms